# MongoDB - Merge Update

Tags: python, mongodb, merge, pymongo, insert-update

I am having a little problem updating a MongoDB document (using pymongo). I have found several answers for similar questions that didn't work out for me.

Background: I am crawling some websites and saving information to a MongoDB.

Assume I got the following document from a web page and stored in a MongoDB collection:

```
original_doc = {
    'id': some_id,
    'data': {
        'key1': value1,
        'key2': value2
    }
}
```

After some time, I may want to crawl the same page again and get the following document:

```
new_doc = {
    'id': some_id,
    'data': {
        'key2': new_value2,
        'new_key3': new_value3
    }
}
```

Now I want to update the already existing MongoDB document in the collection so it looks like this:

```
updated_doc = {
    'id': some_id,
    'data': {
        'key1': value1,
        'key2': new_value2,
        'new_key3': new_value3
    }
}
```

So basically the old document should be overwritten with the new document, but without erasing / losing data from the original document, that does not exist in the new document.

I first thought I could use the $set to update the document, but then the (key1, value1) entry gets lost. And I do not know the key of the new entry as I am not in control of the data returned by the website, so I can't just use {$set: {data.new_key3: new_doc}} either.

Is there a solution for this?

Answer (score 1):

You should use `_id as selector` to update document. The query will be like following query...

```
db.collection.update({"_id" : ObjectId("55c789499dd5f5f78633da59") //add mongoId to match here},
{ $set:{"data.key2":"new_value2","data.new_key3":"new_value3"}})
```

**This query will update existing document with new data. The mongoId will be same as old document**.

Comment: Thank you for your help! But this is what I mentioned above and didn't work for me. Since I get my documents from other websites, I don't know the name of the keys (e.g. "data.key2") in advance. Is there a generic way of doing this?

Comment: But you didn't mentioned your keys are dynamic. isn't it?

Comment: Sorry, I should have pointed it out more clearly. That's what I wrote in my initial question: "I do not know the key of the new entry as I am not in control of the data returned by the website, so I can't just use {$set: {data.new_key3: new_doc}} either"
Thank you again for your help!